# Why async await doesn't working on IIS, but it's working on IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, iis, async-await, iis-express

I don't understand, why async/await doesn't resolve problem with IIS threads.

**I see that we have limit on IIS threads equals 10, when I use IIS and no limits for IIS express.**

I add 2 methods in HomeController  for repeat this problem. One of them (method) use Thread.Sleep and other use async/await.

Of course I use logger (NLog) for describe this problem in more details.

I use apache-jmeter-3.0 with 100 parallel request for one url as stress test.

**I was very surprised when the test execution time was approximately the same for IIS and not same for IIS express.**

Some code from HomeController

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private const int _waitTimeout = 30000;
    private const string _beginFmt = "Begin method; Count = {0}; OperId = {1};";
    private const string _endFmt =   "End method  ; Count = {0}; OperId = {1};";

    private static volatile int _counter = 0;
    private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public JsonResult GetWithThreadSleep()
    {
        Guid operId = Guid.NewGuid();

        _logger.Info(_beginFmt, Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter), operId);

        Thread.Sleep(_waitTimeout);

        _logger.Info(_endFmt, Interlocked.Decrement(ref _counter), operId);

        return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    public async Task<JsonResult> GetWithTaskAwait()
    {
        Guid operId = Guid.NewGuid();

        _logger.Info(_beginFmt, Interlocked.Increment(ref _counter), operId);

        await Task.Delay(_waitTimeout);

        _logger.Info(_endFmt, Interlocked.Decrement(ref _counter), operId);

        return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Log format

```
    <target xsi:type="File" 
            name="f" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${threadid} @ ${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss} @ ${level} @${aspnet-sessionid} @ ${message} @ ${callsite:className=False}" 
    />
```

**Test scenario one**: I send 100 parallel GET request to method **GetWithTaskAwait** and expect that the requests will be processed **faster than** 5 minutes, because thread should reused.

But this is not the case. Test duration equals 5 minutes

```
1 @ 23:43:54 @ Info @ @ MVC Count = 1; @ .ctor
1 @ 23:43:54 @ Info @ @ APP Count = 1; @ Application_Start
11 @ 23:44:06 @ Info @ @ MVC Count = 2; @ .ctor
...
13 @ 23:45:36 @ Info @ @ End method  ; Count = 8; OperId = 28818fba-5535-4c01-9d6d-5efa3943cf37; @ MoveNext
19 @ 23:45:36 @ Info @ @ Begin method; Count = 9; OperId = c3cd3339-ec29-4625-adb9-62d5c72831b0; @ GetWithTaskAwait
12 @ 23:45:36 @ Info @ @ End method  ; Count = 9; OperId = d1686c05-ca7a-400c-8c17-43dfb7b9218a; @ MoveNext
16 @ 23:45:36 @ Info @ @ Begin method; Count = 10; OperId = c1ec5517-649c-4733-9db3-e666e648abae; @ GetWithTaskAwait
13 @ 23:45:36 @ Info @ @ End method  ; Count = 9; OperId = fbcfc9d9-fb84-456b-82a1-a0d593ef0815; @ MoveNext
...
26 @ 23:49:06 @ Info @ @ End method  ; Count = 8; OperId = 766d4bc5-3739-4e20-a242-1f114dd44442; @ MoveNext
22 @ 23:49:06 @ Info @ @ End method  ; Count = 7; OperId = 0ba18b30-11c9-49fe-8c94-40bbfa817e88; @ MoveNext
16 @ 23:49:06 @ Info @ @ End method  ; Count = 9; OperId = 6d7afd57-6128-4bee-bf32-92de7cfc6a34; @ MoveNext
26 @ 23:49:06 @ Info @ @ End method  ; Count = 6; OperId = 4c022744-9932-4f94-be1d-b982e36460f2; @ MoveNext
22 @ 23:49:06 @ Info @ @ End method  ; Count = 5; OperId = 05476e6a-106f-4da5-b99b-098b90dbab89; @ MoveNext
16 @ 23:49:07 @ Info @ @ End method  ; Count = 4; OperId = 3aba1ad2-56b0-4cf5-8aee-7e918eca9fba; @ MoveNext
27 @ 23:49:07 @ Info @ @ End method  ; Count = 3; OperId = ef972cdd-7992-4816-9452-ecabaf189767; @ MoveNext
15 @ 23:49:07 @ Info @ @ End method  ; Count = 2; OperId = 9a0f735e-bf6b-4217-b2ef-8abd9ce01d27; @ MoveNext
30 @ 23:49:07 @ Info @ @ End method  ; Count = 0; OperId = cc75b44a-4e8d-4534-9906-40bddc027267; @ MoveNext
33 @ 23:49:07 @ Info @ @ End method  ; Count = 1; OperId = bbef36b3-051b-444d-858a-2766bcfcd12b; @ MoveNext
...
26 @ 23:49:49 @ Info @ @ MVC Count = 10; @ Dispose
30 @ 23:50:19 @ Info @ @ MVC Count = 9; @ Dispose
16 @ 23:50:49 @ Info @ @ MVC Count = 8; @ Dispose
```

**Test scenario two**: I send 100 parallel GET request to method **GetWithThreadSleep** and expect that the requests will be processed **equal** 5 minutes, because thread shouldn't reuse.

```
1 @ 00:15:41 @ Info @ @ MVC Count = 1; @ .ctor
1 @ 00:15:41 @ Info @ @ APP Count = 1; @ Application_Start
11 @ 00:16:14 @ Info @ @ MVC Count = 2; @ .ctor
...
15 @ 00:16:15 @ Info @ @ Begin method; Count = 8; OperId = cedb5075-405c-4c23-93cb-388dc34537ba; @ GetWithThreadSleep
17 @ 00:16:15 @ Info @ @ MVC Count = 10; @ .ctor
17 @ 00:16:15 @ Info @ @ Begin method; Count = 9; OperId = 777d7464-f900-48c1-991f-ef8c8f7e6e86; @ GetWithThreadSleep
18 @ 00:16:16 @ Info @ @ MVC Count = 11; @ .ctor
18 @ 00:16:16 @ Info @ @ Begin method; Count = 10; OperId = f9b4b717-94a5-4196-958f-c1234d19514c; @ GetWithThreadSleep
12 @ 00:16:45 @ Info @ @ End method  ; Count = 8; OperId = 9e40acd4-888f-4656-a5a3-c5a1d210cc88; @ GetWithThreadSleep
5 @ 00:16:45 @ Info @ @ End method  ; Count = 9; OperId = b068e03e-37e9-446e-ad42-c9ab4c30da93; @ GetWithThreadSleep
11 @ 00:16:45 @ Info @ @ End method  ; Count = 7; OperId = 22e510e5-62f7-4bc8-8ab0-fdeb3080e250; @ GetWithThreadSleep
...
18 @ 00:21:15 @ Info @ @ End method  ; Count = 2; OperId = 169ef436-6b27-4f4c-a3ca-0b18a5a796cf; @ GetWithThreadSleep
13 @ 00:21:16 @ Info @cubgm2zsojblkhrwwpixaaej @ End method  ; Count = 1; OperId = ee346be8-17c5-45ac-88b5-67e724250bbf; @ GetWithThreadSleep
12 @ 00:21:16 @ Info @ @ End method  ; Count = 0; OperId = 68d5deaa-95d6-4627-a129-144ffafcc2ef; @ GetWithThreadSleep
13 @ 00:22:11 @ Info @ @ MVC Count = 10; @ Dispose
9 @ 00:22:41 @ Info @ @ MVC Count = 9; @ Dispose
```

Important information:

- IIS version 10.0.14393.0
- .NET Framework 4.5.1
- Windows 10 Pro

You can download full solution from [GitHub](https://github.com/sflusov/IISawait.git)

Comment: May I ask how you see a limit of 10 threads in IIS? Never heard of it before.

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer, I watch value of static variable and analyze of log file. I increment value of static variable in method start and decrement before method complete.

Comment: @StanislavFlusov: The first thing to check is the session state for your requests. Have you turned off session state?

Comment: @StephenCleary, I add attribute SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled) to controller code and receive absolutely the same result. More than, I check that Session property equal null into any method of this Controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIS on a desktop OS (Win 7/8/10) will limit your requests to 10 concurrent.

On server OS's (2008/2012/2016), that limit does not exist.

On IIS Express that limit also does not exists.

The reason for this limit is so you won't use IIS on a desktop OS for production purposes.

https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/windows-8-iis-8-concurrent-requests-limit

Comment: Ran your code (from GitHub) on a desktop and server operating systems (Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012 R2). On Windows 10 it is indeed limited to 10 concurrent requests, as I explained. On W2K12 I was able to run dozens of requests concurrently without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

IIS does not limit threads but concurrent requests (or connections, not sure). Async waits cannot circumvent that limit.

Comment: But the experiment shows that the async/await running perfectly on IIS Express, but does not running on IIS.

Comment: You said that IIS expression does not throttle so that part seems OK. And I say that await does not allow you to circumvent the limit on IIS so that seems correct as well. Am I missing something?